# Pass rendered data- attributes to angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, dropzone.js

I need to pass a data-attribute to an angular controller function. (I'm sure there's a better name, but the context is below):

Dropzone.js has a "preview template".
For every file you upload in the dropzone, it renders the HTML you specify here.

Here's a part of this HTML which is of interest:

```
    <div class="dz-size"><span data-dz-size></span></div>
    <div class="dz-filename"><span data-dz-name></span></div>
```

I would like to do something like:

```
<div class="dz-filename"><span data-dz-name></span></div>
<i class="fa" class="{{getIconFromFilename(dz-name)}}" style="..."></i>
```

Does anyone know the proper syntax for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found complex angular directive for Dropzone [here](https://gist.github.com/compact/8118670)

You can catch file after upload a then set proper class name in Your scope

```
$scope.dropzoneConfig = {
'options': { // passed into the Dropzone constructor
  'url': 'upload.php'
},
'eventHandlers': {
  'sending': function (file, xhr, formData) {
  },
  'success': function (file, response) {
     // set scope icon class from file
  }
}};
```

Comment: I've thought about this. Scope is shared across multiple file uploads, though. So I would still have a problem when trying to find the appropriate file/index in the preview template.

Comment: Actually, solved it this way. Note that for everyone looking to do the same thing, you'll probably be needing to use `$compile` to create a scope per file upload. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32905136/create-angular-scope-on-dom-element

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the [ng-class directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass).
Depending on what your function returns this may work:

```
<i class="fa" ng-class="[getIconFromFilename(dz-name)]"></i>
```

Comment: Could you provide a JSFiddle / Plnkr link with the code? what is dz-name meant to represent?

Comment: http://www.dropzonejs.com/, upload a file, right click on filename and view source