# Create angular scope on DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dom

I need to create a new angular scope and attach it to a DOM element. I'm modifying a third party control so I don't have the option of just using a directive.

I need to do something like:

```
... = thirdPartyCallbackfunction(domElement){
        var myNewScope = $scope.$new(true);
        myNewScope.title = 'Hello';
        domElement.scope = myNewScope; //???
}
```

Also, I've tried adding `ng-scope` manually to the DOM element, but ng-inspector shows me that it's not creating a new child scope.

```
$(domElement).scope();
```

Gives me the root scope when trying that.

The [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$new) weren't very helpful either.

Comment: do you want to create an element or bind a scope item to an existing element?

Comment: The element is already created and in the DOM, I have a reference to said element. Now I want to create a new scope and attach it to it.

Comment: so $compile is what you need

Comment: Hope this helps someone else, this was really hard to find re search terms!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use $compile service.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <p> Top scope: {{number}}</p>
  <p> Top scope: {{myProp}}</p> <!-- Undefined in the top-level scope -->
  <div id = "child">
    <p> New scope: {{myProp}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myCtrl", ["$scope", "$compile", function($scope, $compile){
  $scope.number = 35;
  var myFunc = function(){
    var innerElem = angular.element(document.querySelector("#child"));
    var innerScope = $scope.$new();
    innerScope.myProp = 55;
    var compileFn = $compile(innerElem);
    compileFn(innerScope);
  }
  myFunc();
}]);
```

`$compile` is used to evaluate HTML fragment or DOM element (wrapped in jqLite object). For example, instead of the DOM element, you could have used some html template with inline bindings: 
`var content = "<ul><li ng-repeat='city in cities'>{{city}}</li></ul>"
var list = angular.element(content); //create jqLite object from the template above;`
The next step is to use the `$compile` service object, which is a function that returns another function which will then be used to generate the content.
`var compileFn = $compile(list);`

Once you have the compilation function, you invoke it passing the scope object as the context for the upcoming evaluation, basically linking the element with the scope. 
`compileFn(scope);`
Now bindings/expressions contained within the template will be evaluated using the scope you passed it and update the jqLite object (`list`), but there will be no return value, so in this case you would have to manually add the updated `list` object to DOM. Hope this clarifies the service a bit.

Comment: Could you explain what's happening `$compile(innerElem);`?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile basically it compiles the string or html string to into a template and renders  you usually also enter the scope you want to link it to the scope so something like $compile(html)(scope)